# How to cast String into int in PostgreSql

Tags: string, postgresql, casting

I want to cast string into Integer.
I have a table like this.

Have:

```
ID     Salary
1      "$1,000"
2      "$2,000"
```

Want:

```
ID   Salary
1    1000
2    2000
```

My query

```
Select Id, cast(substring(Salary,2, length(salary)) as int) 
from have
```

I am getting error.

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "1,000"
> SQL state: 22P02

Can anyone please provide some guidance on this.

Comment: are $ and comma always existed in salary value?

Comment: You can use the [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/regexp_replace/#:~:text=PostgreSQL%20REGEXP_REPLACE%20Function%201%20Syntax%202%20Arguments.%20The,this%20name%20as%20follows%20for%20the%20reporting%20purpose.) function `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(salary, ',|\$', '', 'g')::INT FROM test;`

Comment: There is also [to_number](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)  function if you know the maximum number of digits your current could have `SELECT to_number(salary, 'L99999999999') FROM test;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all non-digit characters, then you cast it to an integer:

```
regexp_replace(salary, '[^0-9]+', '', 'g')::int
```

But instead of trying to convert the value every time you select it, fix your database design and convert the column to a proper integer. **Never** store numbers in text columns.

```
alter table bad_design 
     alter salary type int using regexp_replace(salary, '[^0-9]+', '', 'g')::int;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I really can not change the source table, I have to use that column and get it stored into my working table with no comma and converted to number.

Comment: If you really can't fix the broken design, then you will have to use the `regexp_replace()` expression in a SELECT query

Comment: select id,salary, regexp_replace(salary, '[^0-9]+', 'g')::int new_salary  from have

ran this but getting below error

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "g1,000"

Comment: @DharmendraKumarYadav: sorry a typo in the first expression (the second one was correct)

Comment: Be wary of salaries with decimal places or different currencies (or commas as decimal separator) when doing this sort of thing...